# Security issue in catching exceptions in outside methods? Python

Tags: python, security, exception

Is there a *security issue* in catching exceptions through a separate function? For example if I catch an exception in class:

```
def my_function(some_variable):
    try:
        int(some_variable)
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit()
    #other code running
```

As opposed to passing it through some sort of method.

```
def my_function(some_variable)
    check_error(some_variable) #this does the try/except
    #other code running
def check_error(some_variable)
    #does the check
```

Is there a flaw or vulnerability that can be exploited in one or the other, by memory, etc, or is the two methods shown above essentially **the same thing**. I *believe* that python deals with all memory handling automatically. I could be wrong. However, I want to know is there a reason **why** it is good practice to catch exceptions *in method or in an outside method* as shown in the two code samples above.

I understand if there is a lot of checking it is good for an exception method for readability and modularity, but is it good for **security**?

Also this might be a better question to put in chat, but I don't have that capability yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: using `except` will *catch* an `Exception`. Use `raise` to *throw* one

Comment: I can't see any difference between these two examples purely from a security standpoint.

Comment: @C.Nivs hey thanks good _catch_ ;)

Comment: What do you expect to be exploited by handling or raising an exception? *"I want to know is there a reason why it is good practice to catch exceptions in method or in an outside method"* This suggests more a question of style than security